# How to set Java date in RegularTimePeriod in org.jfree.data.time

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I have less experience with jasper reporting.

```
   if (endDate.after(startDate)){
                TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries(stat.clientName , Millisecond.class);
                for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){

                    double Ltbr = stat.getLTBR().get(i);
                    String date = stat.getTimestamp().get(3*i).getDate()+"/"+ stat.getTimestamp().get(3*i).getMonth()+1+"/" + stat.getTimestamp().get(3*i).getYear();
                    Date datetoGraph=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);

                    timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(datetoGraph), Ltbr);

                }
                /*for (int i =0 ; i < timeSeriesList.size(); i++){

                }*/
                dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);

                //  dataset.addSeries(createTimeSeries(stat.clientName, start , end , htlRatio));

            }

            //

        }
```

In the resulting graph x-axis, it shows only millisecond scale values.

When I came with the solution replacing

```
timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(datetoGraph), Ltbr);
```

with

```
timeSeries.add(new Day(datetoGraph), Ltbr);
```

then no data set into the graph.

I need to show only date values on the x-axis.

Comment: I came up with another solution with changing  Millisecond.class  to Day.class   but the results doesnot change

Comment: Try `setDateFormatOverride()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20setDateFormatOverride).

Comment: @trashgod  thank u for your attention but this was totally mycarelessness. instead of   JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart  i have use d  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. For reference, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). Study the code for each factory to see the difference. Note that including a [mcve] will make your answer more useful to others.